# Compress 1 TB file collection into standalone archives each size no more than 2GB

Tags: file-management, compression

I have about 1TB data stored in two drives and I need to compress and encrypt them into independent archives each size must be smaller than 2GB. Exception may be files that are larger than 2GB.

Is there an easier way than manually creating 2GB folders and compressing them (and splitting if necessary)? It takes too long time to do this manually.

----Edit---

I have about 50 000 files total, about half are 1 - 20 MB, about 1000 files are 0.3GB - 10GB which takes about 750 GB.
7-zip provides ability to split archive into smaller files. For example, i can compress folder containing files about 50GB into 25 files. But if one of them gets corrupted most of data may be lost. I want to make these 25 files into standalone archives. If something goes wrong with one file i can use remaining archives.

Comment: Please provide the OS platform and version in order for us to effectively help you.

Comment: Depending on what type of data you're compressing, you could compress each file independently.

Comment: @mdpc i am currently using Windows XP SP3

Comment: @GigaWatt i will update my question.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "independent archive"?  Do you mean that no files should span across multiple archive files?  (For example, 7zip supports split archives)

Comment: @GigaWatt i updated question.

Comment: I will try to create command line application that does this automatically if useful answer will not appear